# Using Fetch api DELETE method with no-cors enabled

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api, http-delete

I am trying to make an API requests that deletes an entity in the backend. My spring server and node.js server are running on different ports.

When I try a fetch request with cors enabled (`mode: "cors"`) I get an error that the request was blocked by the cors policy. When I disabel cors (`mode: "no-cors"`), I get the following error:

```
 Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': 'DELETE' is unsupported in no-cors mode.
```

The code for the request:

```
export async function deleteOneProcessType(id) {
let ret = await fetch(`${restUri}${uri}/${id}`, {
    method: "DELETE",
    mode: "no-cors"
})
```

}

I have similar POST and GET methods whith cors disabled that work just fine.

Comment: The cors policy error means you need to enable it. Remove your 'mode: no-cors' and enable cors request on your backend. Adding 'mode: cors' does not do a lot of change it it isn't enable in your abckend

Comment: Yes I know. I have already enabled cors request in my backend. I already have several POST requests which work without any problem. They are exactly the same as the delete request I mentioned in my question but instead of DELETE they have POST. The problem seems to be that the DELETE method works differently than the POST method but I haven't been able to find a solution

Comment: Is your Backend running on Azure? If so, you must ensure that your javascript frontend is ssl-certified (https)

Answer (score 2):

No need to set **mode: "no-cors"**
Indeed you just need toadjust your backend in order to allow your request

To do so add a WebMvcConfigurer Bean

You can do so using a Configuration class for instance.
You can refer to https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework

As mentionned in the documentation by default only GET and POST requests are allowed.
Then you need to allow DELETE as well

Finally you should have something like that :

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsController()
{
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("[Your_backend_server_URI_here]/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("[Your_frontend_URL_here]")
                    .allowedMethods("PUT","DELETE","GET","POST");
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`POST` and `GET` are considered `simple requests` where you can use `mode: "no-cors"` . You cannot do this with DELETE and PUT for example. I suggest you to use `Proxy server` for all your API calls. With a Proxy server you can solve CORS error.

Example: you want to delete an entity to this api: `https://test.api.com/customer/1`.

In **package.json** add the following line:

```
"proxy": "https://test.api.com"
```

Your request in the component:

```
export async function deleteOneProcessType(id) {
let ret = await fetch(`/customer/${id}`, {
    method: "DELETE"
})
```